# What is the regular expression for the below html?

Tags: php

I want to add to a cart 'title', but not get it.

```
$file_contents= '<div class="actions"><button onclick="" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button></div>';
```

Using preg_match_all kindly reply me

Answer (score 2):

Simple as this -

```
<?php
$file_contents= '<div class="actions"><button onclick="" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button></div>';
echo strip_tags($file_contents);
```

**Update**

```
<?php
$file_contents= '<div class="actions"><button onclick="" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button></div>';
$new_string = str_replace("Add to Cart","Pre Order",$file_contents);
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: Hello i want find add to cart & replace with Pre Order how to do this?